# How can I return the single MIN value of a column in an SQL dataframe as a scalar?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe

I just want one value from the SQL database I am accessing. Is this possible? Or does it have to be returned as some kind of database. I just want the minimum value of the row of this particular column

```
event = sql("SELECT MIN(epoch_ms) FROM logs WHERE vin = '"+vin+"'")
```

When I print out `event`, I get this:

```
   _col0
0  1544248618120
```

The type is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. What I want is just an int the output.

Comment: Yes, you can get one value. please provide more details like your input data and expected output?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, updated my question.

Comment: @miyesven: Is event really a pandas dataframe? It looks like you are using spark in which case it should be a spark dataframe.

Comment: @Shaido thanks for pointing it out, that was an old part of the code that I forgot to delete. yes i ran it with sql(....), not spark.sql(...) and returned the pandas dataframe. I was running presto and not spark in jupyter. update: edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get a particular value by querying SQL database. Once you connect the particular rdbms/external data source by using odbc libraries.